# reshaping based on condition in r

Tags: r, reshape

I'm having a trouble finding what I want the outcome to be. I'm trying to reshape my data first to wide format and back to long format. Here is a very simple code:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(
 id = rep(c("one", "two"), each=4),
 program = rep(1:4, 2),
 days = sample(1:100, 8, replace=FALSE),
 min.date = sample(2000:2015, 8, replace = TRUE),
 max.date = sample(2014:2019, 8, replace = TRUE))
```

dat:

```
id  program days min.date max.date
one 1       27       2010     2018 
one 2       37       2000     2019 
one 3       57       2003     2016
one 4       89       2002     2018 
two 1       20       2010     2019 
two 2       86       2006     2016 
two 3       97       2012     2018 
two 4       62       2014     2014
```

How I wanted to reshape this long data is to use the `min.date` and `max.date` variables to create a wide format for each program. This is my expected wide format:

```
id  program.1.2010 program.1.2011  program.1.2012 program.1.2013 ... 
one             27             27              27             27 ...
two             20             20              20             20 ...
```

Essentially, each id would have days of each program taken between `min.date` and `max.date` in wide format. Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: What code did you use to reshape and what happened?

Comment: Your expected output is not matching the input

Comment: Are you looking for a single column for each min.date-max.date-program combination?

Comment: @iod yes that's what I'm looking for. I can't seem to figure out what to do for the first step even

Comment: Looking at your desires result, it looks like what you're actually looking for is a single column for each year-program combination, with data only included in program-years that fall within the min-max range for that program/id. That's... probably not a good data structure. What are you ACTUALLY trying to achieve? Sounds like an XY problem

Comment: @iod I actually want to turn this back into a long balanced format where each id has year from 2000 to 2019 and for every year has 4 programs' days where id participated. I thought that in order to do that, I would first need to turn this data into a wide format and then back to long format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
require(dplyr)
df1 %>% group_by(id,program) %>% 
mutate(daterange=paste(seq(min.date,max.date),collapse=",")) %>%
separate_rows(daterange,sep=",") %>% select(-min.date,-max.date) %>% 
spread(program,days)
```

The `mutate` creates a string of all the years within each range, separated by a comma.
The `separate_rows` then takes this string, breaks it down at the commas, and creates a new row for each value, which we can then just `spread` to create what I think was your actual desired format. That last step may be unnecessary, depending on how I interpret your comment above.
Result:

```
   id    daterange `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`
   <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1 one   2000     NA    37    NA    NA
 2 one   2001     NA    37    NA    NA
 3 one   2002     NA    37    NA    89
 4 one   2003     NA    37    57    89
 5 one   2004     NA    37    57    89
 6 one   2005     NA    37    57    89
 7 one   2006     NA    37    57    89
 8 one   2007     NA    37    57    89
 9 one   2008     NA    37    57    89
10 one   2009     NA    37    57    89
# ... with 24 more rows
```

Comment: wow yes that's exactly what I was going for. Sorry my question wasn't clear.